# HTML, javascript not responding to run a batch file

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file

when I launch this is chorme and click on submit button, the script doesnt respond. I have placed this html file, script.bat file in the same location. No idea why it is not getting responded.

```
<html>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunc() {
            var x = document.getElementById("ip").value;
            //window.open('script.bat')
            var MyObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            MyObject.Run("script.bat");
            if (x != "")
                window.alert(x);
            else
                window.alert("Invalid IP");
        }
        </script>

        <body>
            Enter the IP:
            <input type="text" id="ip" />
            <input type="Submit" onclick="myfunc()" />
        </body>

    </html>
```

script.bat file has one liner, which creates a file with content "Hello" as below:

`echo "Hello" > temp.txt`

Comment: Why do you think ActiveX should work in Chrome?

Comment: try to set `.hta` extension

Comment: I need to host the html file in apache. Can u give me any alternative?